# How to make images autoscale regardless of height (like on tumblr blogs)

Tags: jquery, css

Im not sure what this technique is called, so the title of this thread is might be wrong.

A perfect example of what I am talking about can be seen here: http://designunitjournal.tumblr.com/

I guess there is some algorithm that calculates the position every image should have, and makes it fit.

So far, i've just made a copy of the blog that i am referring to, which can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Y325B/

And here:

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="content">
    <div class="box">
        <img src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/8d63dca97b6a44757b6ea53fd0b9b394/tumblr_mpo9rzUkfE1qzgzyuo1_500.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <img src="http://25.media.tumblr.com/6b5d13fd007284d82356467dfe614d7f/tumblr_mx8mmrzA2Z1sus27uo1_500.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <img src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/a76eb60aea322fa4d5f97315ac50705b/tumblr_mfer9k8llm1rzg8gso1_500.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <img src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/03a917bc59c9f311fee125fa8f2d5def/tumblr_mx37oyJlxM1rb8i4no1_500.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <img src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/16dfda5931bd241038a61f8a48c811ea/tumblr_mwgglh2EiF1r6ky2bo1_500.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <img src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/a3fd48077d16fc09a459720ff315e5f9/tumblr_mw3gnhQeIF1qc6bmco1_500.jpg/>
    </div>
</div>
 </body>
```

CSS:

```
.box img {
max-width: 100%;
border: 0px;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
opacity: 1;
}

.box {
    width: 290px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 45px;
    margin-bottom: 45px;
    position: relative;
}
```

If i want three images per row, how would i go about removing the space that there is between the rows (automatically)?

Look at the red arrows in the below image. I want the images to go up, where there is free space.

[image]

Comment: None of the image URLs are loading for me, but have you considered just setting the widths to percentages?

Comment: I edited the link, the images should be visible now

Comment: What's wrong with http://jsfiddle.net/TxR64/ ?

Comment: Thanks! There is nothing wrong, only that it changes the structure of the markup - but that is ok. Do you have an suggestion on how to make three images per row, with your example? :)

Comment: Like I said in my answer below, you merely have to add additional `.col` divs for every column that you need.

Comment: Yes, but ther first three images will be stack beneath each other instead of next to each other. Is this the only solution?

Comment: That is likely because the size of the window is too small to fit them all. If you prefer using horisontal scrollbars, I would suggest wrapping all the columns in a single container with a fixed width or `white-space: nowrap;` I updated my answer with a new fiddle to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of different ways of achieving this effect, depending on your structural requirements. However, spontaneously I would simply add three containers (one for each column) with `display: inline-block` or `float: left` and an appropriate width. Then you just have to populate them with the images where you set `width: 100%;`.

If you want to prevent the columns from breaking when you resize your window, I would suggest wrapping the columns in a single container width `white-space: nowrap`;

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TxR64/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can limit 3 image per row by change CSS attribute in `.box` to `width: 30%`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/iamcem/5q5SF/)

Answer (score 0):

Use width percentages. For three in a row, use 33.3% to be exact. The `.box` class is setting the width of the parent div the actual image goes inside. This way the images just crop if they're larger than the container. You also want to `float: left` and `display: inline-block` them too, to get them to display horizontally.

To get spacing between them, you could do a few things. I would try adding padding to the `.box` class first. If that doesn't get the look you want, use margins around them. You'll probably have to bring down the width % a little so that it fits all the way across. So for 33.3%, you could try 31% maybe.

You can also set a `max-height: ...` for the `.box` class if you want.